# why npm install does not respect version in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Nodejs version - `14.17.3`
npm version - `6.14.13`

I am confused over the difference in package versions -
the one I have declared in `package.json` is different than
the one that is being installed by `npm install` command.

package.json  -

```json
{
  "name": "training-project-metadata",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "module1.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "tildify": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "bundleDependencies": [
    "tildify"
  ]
}
```

If I run `npm install` command, this is the package-lock.json that is being created -

```json
{
  "name": "training-project-metadata",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 1,
  "requires": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "tildify": {
      "version": "3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/tildify/-/tildify-3.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-9ZLMl75qnTLr7oSEmWJbKemFS/fP4TMBiF6PFwGwLpgobebU1ehXoGbadJ+7jT8fjaz2G82JgN9G4taz+o1j1w==",
      "dev": true
    }
  }
}
```

I even tried removing ^ symbol from package.json to make it exact version - but that didn't help.
What I have found is if I run this command explicitly - only then the correct version 2.0.0 is installed.

```
npm install tildify@2.0.0 --save-dev
```

Can anyone please help me understand why it doesn't work for `npm install` command?

Thank you!

Comment: what is bundleDependencies? maybe it tells npm to ignore the specified version in the devDependencies?

Comment: yarn1 also has same result?

Comment: It just tells which bundles are going to be in tar file - if I plan to use npm pack command

Comment: did you try to delete the package-lock.json file and run npm install again?

Comment: yes, I did delete package-lock.json and node-modules folder and ran npm install command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json)

Answer (score 1):

The similar things happened to me. For me, I want to install

> "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.71"

But turns out, npm installed this for me.

> 5.0.0-alpha.79

That's because you have specified `^` before the version number. I removed the `^` and try `npm install` again, it installed excatly the version that I want.
For more information about the meaning of the symbol, you can find in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25861938/15603575